Create Apache Superset chart using DuckDb and Iceberg table raises "virtual dataset query cannot consist of multiple statements"
Creating chart in Apache Superset using DuckDB and Iceberg table using the following statements:
LOAD iceberg;
SELECT * FROM iceberg_scan('/ake-data/iceberg/ake/my_iceberg_table/metadata/00001-15a10a3d-7e09-497a-925e-f8f0fd3ff61c.metadata.json');

Raises the following exception/error.

Unexpected error Error:Virtual dataset query cannot consist of multiple statements

How to create a chart in Apache Superset using DuckDB and Iceberg table ?
